# How can I be notified by QItemSelectionModel when no items are selected?

Tags: qt, pyqt, qt5, signals-slots, pyqt5

I would like to know when there is no longer a selection in a QTableView, but alas, I don't receive [QItemSelectionModel.selectionChanged](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qitemselectionmodel.html#selectionChanged) when this happens. That is to say; a selection is first made in the table view, for which I receive a selectionChanged signal from the selection model, but when the selection is undone I don't receive another signal.

I connect to the selectionChanged signal like so:

```
# view is a QTableView
view.selectionModel().selectionChanged.connect(
    lambda: print('Selection changed')
 )
```

What must I do to get notified by the selection model that the selection is no longer valid?

Comment: How do you "undo" the selection?

Comment: @vahancho Just click beyond the rightmost column, so nothing is selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out to not be quite true that QItemSelectionModel.selectionChanged doesn't get emitted when items are deselected, at least that's how it currently works for me. In fact, I receive this signal with an empty QItemSelection for the `indexes` argument.